# Linear algebra: issue with question about rank and signature of quadratic form

Tags: linear-algebra

I've been working through some problems at the end of our lecture course and I have an issue with a certain question. I reproduce it here (the comments in partheses are done by me):

> Let $f_1,...f_{t+u}$ be linear functionals on the finite dimensional real vector space $V$ (i.e. they are members of the dual space $V^*$). Show that $Q(\vec{x})=f_1(\vec{x})^2+...+f_t(\vec{x})^2-f_{t+1}(\vec{x})^2-...-f_{t+u}(\vec{x})^2$ is a quadratic form on $V$ (done that). Suppose $Q$ has rank $p+q$ and signature $p-q$. Prove that $p \leq t$ and $q \leq u$.

Now, correct me if I am wrong. This means $2q$ represents the number of negative eigenvalues of the matrix representing $Q$, or the dimension of its (largest) negative-definite subspace. My first instinct was, how can we assume this number to be even? Indeed, it is not necessarily so. If $\dim V=2$, $Q(\vec{x})=Q(x,y)=(x+y)^2-(x-y)^2=4xy$ has rank $2$ and signature $1$, and their difference is odd.

Allowing $q$ to be fractional, surely we have anyway that the dimension of the negative definite subspace is less than or equal to $u$, giving $q \leq \frac{u}{2}$? (I have done this in more detail personally by picking bases for the dual spaces but I omit it here)

This now means that we don't have $p \leq t$. To cut a long story short, if we change the statement of the question to rank=$p+q$, singature=$p$ so that $q$ is the number of negative eigenvalues and $p$ the number of positive ones, all the problems vanish and we get the required inequalities.

Now, who has got it horribly wrong, me or the question?

Comment: The signature of a matrix is not usually defined to be a single number. Your notations are nonstandard, so please explain them.

Comment: @darijgrinberg certainly. http://mathworld.wolfram.com/MatrixSignature.html, where the rank is in my case $p+q$ and the signature $p$.

Comment: Actually, @darijgrinberg I checked again, it is not what I just said according to our course, hence the confusion. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction :) (you could post a short answer if you want an accept)